# Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.40805)' evaluates to false.

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I got this in log file when I tried to install Visual Studio 11 Developer Previews. How to make it true?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. If it's < v4.5.4..., then I think it causes the error message of not having the minimum version installed. There must be some other issue that's causing the install to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for your error message, [I found this one](http://forums.asp.net/post/4618676.aspx) that says:

> If any one else get this error during installing Visual Studio 2011
>   Developer Preview then the simple answer is that thier download
>   package is corrupted. I just downloaded again Visual Studio 2011
>   Developer Preview, installtion got succeed.
>
> Note that you should redownload it, even if you see the size of your
>   VS package is same with download link.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing the [.NET 4.5](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225767) framework separately before you attempt to run the Visual Studio 11 installer? It should also be in located within the packages\dotnetframework directory of your Visual Studio 11 image.

**Edit:**

Seeing how it's also complaining about VersionNT, do you meet the minimum operating system requirements?

> [System requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=27538)
>
> Supported Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows 7,
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)
> - Windows Server Developer Preview (x64)

Comment: @IAdapter Is this the only error in your log? Could you include the full log in your question?